# How do I add a local user to a box that uses LDAP authenticaiton?

Tags: users, administration, ldap

I'm working with a box that uses LDAP for user authentication.  However, I need to add a local user to run some services and I don't want non-person users junking up the LDAP directory.  Does anyone know the command/options I would use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On most systems (including Linux), `useradd` and `adduser` only support local users (and ditto for `userdel`, `usermod`, `groupadd`, `groupdel`, `groupmod`, `addgroup`). Use any of these tools.

Comment: ... well that was easier than I thought.  For some reason I was thinking that these tools would also be linked to LDAP.